# Writing objects in different classes in Java

Tags: java, class, composition

> Define two classes, Patient and Billing, whose Objects are records for a clinic. 
>   Derive patient from the class person. A class Person has a name, it has methods for setting and getting the name. It also has a function to display the output and a method hasSameName that checks if names are equal.
>   A patient record has the patients name(defined in the class person) and identification number(use the type String). **A Billing object will contain a patient object and a doctor object**
>   A Doctor record has the doctor’s name—defined in the class Person—a specialty as a string (for example Paediatrician, Obstetrician, General Practitioner, and so on), and an office visit fee (use the type double). 
>   Give your Patient and Billing classes a reasonable complement of constructors and accessor 
>   methods, and an equal’s method as well.
>   Write a test program that creates at least two patients, at least two doctors and create an array of type Person and process the objects polymorphically. **Then create at least two billing records and then displays the total income from the billing records.**

This is obviously a HW I'm struggling in, to be specific what should I write in the Billing class? How I am supposed to relate the patient record and billing and doctor record?

Comment: Show us what work you've done so far.  Have you covered concepts in class yet like *'has-a'* and *'is-a'*?  You may need to ask your professor for a refresher.

Comment: You've nothing to lose by experimenting and trying some solutions on your own first, and you've much to gain. This way if you are still stuck, you can post your code and a much more specific and answerable question. Why not give it a go?

Comment: Try something on your own. The community can best help you if you already have something to debug rather than just an assignment question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question regarding the `Billing` class and how you would associate the `Patient` and `Doctor`, I think your `Billing` class might look something like this (to start):

```
public class Billing {

private Patient p;
private Doctor dr;

public Billing(Patient p, Doctor dr) {
    this.p = p;
    this.dr = dr;
}

public Doctor getDoctor() {
    return dr;
}

public void setDoctor(Doctor newDoctor) {
    dr = newDoctor;
}

public Patient getPatient() {
    return p;
}

public void setPatient(Patient newPatient) {
    p = newPatient;
}
}
```

I hope that has given you a nudge in the right direction.

EDIT: Code enhanced from first suggestion.

Comment: I tried this, the output is null although i wrote an object in the main method.

Comment: public class Billing {
private Doctor bill;
private Patient patientName;
private Doctor doctorName;
public Billing (Patient patientName,Doctor doctorName,Doctor bill ){
this.bill=bill;
this.patientName=patientName;
}

    public Billing(Patient p1, Doctor d1) {
        
    }

Comment: OK, looking at your code, you've got 2 `Doctor`s in your `Billing` class. I'll edit my answer to flesh it out a bit more for you.

Comment: This exactly answers my question, Thank you and I just wrote it in my own and the program run successfully.